# Doubly linked list reimplemented with smart pointers

Tags: c++, linked-list, pointers

I need some suggestions on my reimplementation of a doubly linked list with smart pointers since I'm new to smart pointers in C++.

I read some docs on smart pointers and found out there are `shared_ptr<Obj>`, `unique_ptr<Obj>` and `weak_ptr<Obj>`. I only use `shared_ptr<Obj>` in my current code, but I'm not sure how to use `unique_ptr<Obj>` in my doubly linked list. I would like someone can give me some pointers on how and where to use `unique_ptr<Obj>` in my DLL.

```
class Node{
    public:
        int data;
        Node(int data){
            this->data = data;
        }
    public:
        shared_ptr<Node> prev;
        shared_ptr<Node> next;
};

class LinkedList{
    public:
        shared_ptr<Node> head;
        shared_ptr<Node> tail;
    public:
        LinkedList(){}

        void fun(){
            printf("fun()\n");
        }

        void append(shared_ptr<Node> node){
            if(!head){
                head = node;
                tail = head;
            }else{
                tail->next = node;
                node->prev = tail;
                tail = node;
            }
        }

        void print(){
            shared_ptr<Node> curr = head;
            while(curr){
                printf("[%d]\n", curr->data);
                curr = curr->next;
            }
        }
        void remove(shared_ptr<Node> node){
            shared_ptr<Node> curr = head;
            if(node && curr){
                while(curr){
                    if(curr == node){
                        if(curr->prev == nullptr){
                            if(curr->next == nullptr){
                                // [curr] 
                                node.reset();
                                head.reset();
                                tail.reset();
                            }else{
                                // [curr]->[] 
                                shared_ptr<Node> next = curr->next;
                                curr->next.reset();
                                next->prev.reset();
                                head = next;
                            }
                        }else{
                            if(curr->next == nullptr){
                                // []->[curr] 
                                shared_ptr<Node> prev = curr->prev;
                                curr->prev.reset();
                                prev->next.reset();
                                tail = prev;
                            }else{
                                // []->[curr]->[]
                                shared_ptr<Node> next = curr->next;
                                shared_ptr<Node> prev = curr->prev;
                                next->prev = prev;
                                prev->next = next;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    curr = curr->next;
                }
            }
        }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

**Summary**

This is obviously a personal opinion, but I don't really like the interface you've defined for your list.  By defining your methods in terms of a `shared_ptr<Node>`, you're making the caller responsible for constructing Nodes.  It seems like Node should be an implementation detail of your list.  Otherwise, since the caller has complete access to the Node they can iterate the list and modify it without the `LinkedList` class being called at all.

I'd define the interface in terms of the Data that is to be stored, currently this is an `int`, so you would have something like this:

```
void append(int newValue)
```

Or you may want to define your list in terms of a template and take in a pointer of the relevant type.  This could be a `shared_ptr` if ownership of the data doesn't pass solely to your list, or it could be a `unique_ptr` if the node that references it will be the owner of the Data.

**Append**

Looking at your current implementation, what happens if a `Node` is passed in that already has its `prev` and `next` pointers populated (with the given interface I could assume that I could insert a Node chain).  These pointers aren't checked, they're overwritten.  This is part of why I don't like the interface...

**Remove**

What happens if you're asked to remove a node that isn't in the list?  Currently nothing.  It feels like this method should either be returning an indicator that the object has been removed, or more likely throwing an exception to indicate that it hasn't..

Answer (score 3):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your code.

### Make sure to `#include` all required headers

This program calls `printf` and uses `shared_ptr` but does not include the corresponding headers.  Fix that by adding these lines:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
```

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.  It isn't necessarily wrong to use, but be aware of when you absolutely shouldn't do it (such as in header files).

### Prefer `iostream`s to `printf`

If you're writing C++, it's usually better to write using `iostream`s rather than `printf` because `printf` uses a very loose coupling of object to type (and incurs a runtime cost) while an `iostream` has a much better coupling and moves more of its processing to compile time.  In this code, rather than this:

```
printf("[%d]\n", curr->data);
```

write this:

```
std::cout << '[' << curr->data << "]\n";
```

### Rethink the interface

As written, the code has the following member functions:

```
LinkedList();
void fun();
void print();
void append(std::shared_ptr<Node> node);
void remove(std::shared_ptr<Node> node);
```

Is this a reasonable interface?  My answer would be an emphatic "no!"  First, the `fun()` function seems to be some kind of experiment and should probably be omitted.  Second, all of the functions return `void` -- that doesn't really make much sense.  Third, and most importantly, the use of `std::shared_ptr` means that the caller has to create and pass in a `std::shared_ptr<Node>` which isn't a very good interface design because it requires the caller to have intimate knowledge of the design of your data structure.  Better would be to have an interface that allows passing just the contents of a node (an `int` in this case), and the `print()` would be better expressed as a friend function:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const LinkedList &list);
```

### Think carefully about object ownership

The design employs `std::shared_ptr` which implies multiple ownership.  This might make sense for multithreaded code, but not really for a generic linked list.

### Fix the bug

If the caller uses your interface like this:

```
LinkedList mylist;
mylist.append(std::make_shared<Node>(Node(7)));
mylist.append(nullptr);
mylist.append(std::make_shared<Node>(Node(42)));
```

the program crashes.  That's because it never checks to make sure that the incoming pointer is not `nullptr`.  Any time you write code that deals with pointers, it's important to make such checks.